# XPath doesn't recognize different tables in datagrit

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to automate tests to test datagrid with several tables. When I expand first table it shows the rows, each of them also could be expanded and the next table in hierarchy corresponding with this row appears.

My goal is to get column names separately from both tables. When I use XPATH `//thead[@class = 'k-table-thead']` program found two table headers successfully, but when I try to get elements with column names of single table `(//thead[@class = 'k-table-thead'][0] or [1])`, for example like this: `//thead[@class = 'k-table-thead'][1]/th` or `//thead[@class = 'k-table-thead'][2]/th` it takes all the column names from both tables and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following html

```
<body>
  <table>
    <thead class="k-table-thead">
      <th>First th of the first thead</th>
      <th>Second th of the first thead</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <thead class="k-table-thead">
      <th>First th of the first thead</th>
      <th>Second th of the first thead</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

`//thead[@class = 'k-table-thead'][1]/th` will normally select all `th`'s of the first `thead` within a `table`

`//thead[@class = 'k-table-thead'][2]/th` will normally select select all `th`'s of the **second** `thead` within a table, probably **never anything**, because most tables have only one thead.

You have some alternatives

```
(//thead[@class = 'k-table-thead'])[2]/th
```

will select of all `thead`s the second one, and of that `thead` all `th`'s

or

```
//table[thead[@class = 'k-table-thead']][2]/thead/th
```

will select all th-elements of the `thead` of the second `table` that has the appropriate `thead`